# Why is Rails displaying memory addresses on my page?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

My view:

```
<h1><%= @territory.name %></h1>
<%= link_to 'List of Territories', territories_path %>
<%= render 'shared/address_form' %>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td><strong>Name</strong></td>
    <td><strong>Street</strong></td>
    <td><strong>District</strong></td>
    <td><strong>Note</strong></td>
  <tr>

  <%= @addresses.each do |address| %>
  <tr>
    <td><%= address.name %></td>
    <td><%= address.street %></td>
    <td><%= address.district %></td>
    <td><%= address.note %></td>
  </tr>
  <% end %>
</table>
```

The form I render here is:

```
<%= form_for [@territory, @new_address] do |f| %>
<div>
  <p>
    <%= f.label :address %><br />
    <%= f.text_area :address %>
  </p>
</div>
<div class='file-wrapper'>
  <%= f.submit "Submit" %>
</div>
<% end %>
```

Here is the territories controller, where the instance variable addresses is defined:

```
class TerritoriesController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @territories = Territory.all
  end

  def show
    @territory = Territory.find(params[:id])
    @new_address = @territory.addresses.build
    @addresses = @territory.addresses
  end
  .
  .
  .
```

Why is Rails displaying

```
#<Address:0x7e088224>#<Address:0x7e0881d4>#<Address:0x7e088134>#<Address:0x7e088094>#  <Address:0x7e087ff4>#<Address:0x7e087f54>#<Address:0x7e087eb4>#<Address:0x7e087e14>#<Address:0x7e087d74>#<Address:0x7e0bce48>
```

after the form and before the table?

Thanks
Thomas

Comment: What form? Your code starts at the table. Show the code before that please.

Comment: Sorry, I must have been late. I've just updated the content of the post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check your layouts (app/views/layouts/*). Most likely you have included some ERB code in the one that is being rendered with this page that displays these addresses. Is that the full code of your view?

Edit: I found your solution. Right now, you have `<%= @addresses.each ... %>`. The each method runs the block on all elements, and then returns the list of elements. You do not want this code to be displayed. Remove the `=` so that `<%=` is just `<%`

Comment: I don't really see such a place. I just updated the post with showing the correct view and form. You might want to have a look, as I really cannot see the reason for this odd behavior.

Comment: Are name, street, district, note all standard rails fields or do any of them have custom methods? Also, is there any other code in the partial you are rendering?

Comment: Yes, name, street, district, note are all standard rails fields. This is the complete partial. No other code here.

Comment: And BTW I've removed the partial altogether and the memory addresses are still being displayed. So the only way where this can come from is the controller..., because, this is where the instand variable is being set.

Comment: I already added this to the answer itself, but just to make it more clear, Edit: I found your solution. Right now, you have `<%= @addresses.each ... %>`. The each method runs the block on all elements, and then returns the list of elements. You do not want this code to be displayed. Remove the = so that `<%=` is just `<%`

Answer (score 2):

You have some view code somewhere (in a layout or a view helper) that is implicitly calling the `to_s` method of your `Address` model instances. Look for something like `<%= @address %>`.

As you have seen, the non-overridden behaviour of the `to_s` method is to output the memory address of the object instance.

Comment: I just posted the code, but I can't really see doing anything wrong. I've also run the whole thing in the console and id does print the data without the memory addresses.

Answer (score 2):

Those are not memory addresses. Those are instances of your Address class. If you'd override the `to_s` method in that class, you'd see that output there instead. And the reason you see those object printed out is your use of `<%=`. Changing this line

```
<%= @addresses.each do |address| %>
```

to this

```
<% @addresses.each do |address| %>
```

should fix it.

Answer (score 0):

First: I can see no form in your view. 
Second: Your view looks ok.

Have a look at your layout files.